# When compared, two date values which are same, Rails is saying that both the values are different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Today, i have seen weird issue. When two dates whose values are same compared, rails is returning they are unequal. Can anyone explain me why it happens?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `end_of_day` to both sides.

Comment: FYI: Ruby 2.7 changed `Time#inspect` to include sub seconds for easier debugging.

Comment: Please post the code as text not as an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Time` displays with one-second precision, but stores microseconds in `#usec` field (or even nanoseconds - `#usec` does not have to be an integer). Check

```
self.to_date.usec
Time.zone.parse(params["to_date"].to_s).end_of_day.usec
```

and I wager they will not be the same. As Deepak Mahakele suggests, adding `end_of_day` should max out all sub-day fields, including setting `#usec` to `999999.999r`.

Comment: Either that way or `change(hour: 23, min: 59, sec: 59)` for explicit one-second precision.